# How to connect Tata photon +(Huawei EC156) in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, internet, 3g

I am very new to Ubuntu

Can anybody, kindly enlighten me with the procedure of establishing Internet connection on my laptop ?

I am using 3G Tata Photon+ Huawei EC156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Tata DoCoMo 3G on Ubuntu OS, find the step below on [Techulator](http://www.techulator.com/experts/2071-How-use-Tata-Docomo-3G-Ubuntu-OS.aspx). Read them carefully before you take the step and do not miss the step mentioned herein.

> You try to connect Tata DoCoMo 3G stick and boot up Ubuntu / system.
>
> 1. You may choose network connections and click on the 'New Mobile Broadband Connection'
> 2. Select 'continue' in the dialog box and select "India" as country & then click continue.
> 3. It will show the list of service providers, select 'I don't know my provider' option and type 'TATA DOCOMO UMTS', click continue. Note:
>      Don't select 'Tata DoCoMo' since it is for Tata Photon+ (2G) and not
>      for DoCoMo 3G
> 4. Now, under billing dialog, select 'My plan is not listed' option and enter as "tatadocomo3g" as APN, just click 'confirm' and save your
>      settings.
> 5. After these steps, you will get Network Connections, you will find "TATA DOCOMO UMTS connection" option and click on it. In case if it
>      does not connect to internet then you can just unplug and then plug
>      your 3G stick.
> 6. That's it the step, now you can enjoy by using Tata DoCoMo 3G stick with your Ubuntu OS.

Hope this helps!